# Awaiting comments on my idea on android application

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, google-maps-mobile

My idea of android application is :

**This application would be activated by a calendar
entry, showing that the phone user has an appointment
somewhere (i.e. meeting friends in a town 2 hours away).**

- The application would track the phones position and register that
  the user is on his way to the appointment (by checking if the
  user is following the route of Google maps to the destination).
- The phone would keep a status of whether the phone owner
  will arrive on time or be late

I am quite good at webdesign, but on android platform I am just a rookie
any expert good at android please suggest me good place to start with,

my biggest doubt is
                     ***Can i use google maps API to compare mock locations i use in simulator to locations and landmarks in google maps from source  point to destination point?***

I await some thing useful for me to start my work...

Comment: Not an expert there, but why don't you compare current distance from destination point versus previous distance? You wouldn't need to follow the route, just get closer and closer.

Comment: So, what is your actual question? Please simplify this so that the actual question (and only the information related to it) is here. Otherwise, it's too hard to sift through and likely won't get as many good answers.

Comment: My point is,google maps has huge collection of places and landmarks across world,so if we are not sure of the path,we can see path also we can make sure that we are following the path so i think better and flexible idea is to use maps for the same!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [glympse.com](http://glympse.com/) - they do this almost all of this already. It's also against the T&C of google maps to do routing, so I would very carefully read them and determine if your idea defies the T&C.